# What is the proper way to vertically align form radio buttons that are labeled

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get radio buttons to stack on top of each other instead of display side by side.

I have several form labels defined as inline-block with a width of 150, for the purpose of aligning the input boxes.

I Know how to do this without a label, but when the labels sit to the left, I can't figure it out.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="here.php" method="POST">
        <p>
            <label for="bday">Birthday:</label>
            <input type="date" name="bday">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="gender">Gender</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value"male">Male 
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value"female">Female
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="input" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </form>
```

**CSS:**

```
form {
width:356px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
width:150px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

How do I get "female" to sit directly under "male".

I've gotten close but I don't think its the right way. I combined the radio button inputs in a `<p>` then floated its label and itself to the left, added a `<br />`, then cleared the submit button, but it doesn't look that great.

Advice please? Thanks a bunch,
Josh

Comment: if you want the label out to the left you need to put the `label` tags after the input tags. then everything can be `inline-bock` and the `p` tags will create the new set on a new line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. Can you give a link that explains how this works? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest reorganising your HTML, to the following:

```css
form {
  width: 356px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
fieldset {
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  width: 90%;;
}
label {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
fieldset fieldset label {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<form action="here.php" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="bday">Birthday:</label>
    <input type="date" name="bday">
    <!-- a fieldset groups related input elements together -->
    <fieldset>
      <!-- a <legend> labels a section of the <form>, identifying
           the grouped <inputs>, a <label> was utterly wrong for
           this, given it was, and can be, associated with only
           one of the <input>s -->
      <legend>Gender</legend>

      <!-- wrapping the <input> associates the <input> with the appropriate
           (parent) label -->
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</label>
        <!-- inciedentally, the '=' is not optional, and you were
             missing them here to identify the value and its
             associated attribute-value -->
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</label>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="input" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: wrapped `radio` inputs in `label` for better useability is a great suggestion

Comment: Thanks, I understand most of it. Do I have to use css to position the word "gender" so that its aligned with the rest of my form labels? I will try it later. The border of fieldset and placement of the legend text don't suit my design.

Comment: Could I just put "gender" inside a paragraph and give it the same styles as label? Or is that bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

Add a break?

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value"male">Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value"female">Female
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put each of the radio inputs in a div ( or other block element ) and then they will sit on top of each other.  You could then style those divs using CSS for any other styling you want.

Comment: When you do that, the second radio button wraps under the label or legend on the left.

Comment: You can add margin-left to it e.g. style="margin-left:50px;"